# warning unable to restore previously selected frame - cannot open UITabBarController Modally

Tags: ios5, uitabbarcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, uiview-hierarchy

I am trying to present a tabBarController modally. I am trying to do that by following code:

```cs
summaryGraphManager *summary = [[summaryGraphManager alloc] initWithNibName:@"SummaryGraphManager" bundle:nil]; 
    [summary setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    NSLog(@"tabbar: %@",self.parentViewController);
    [self.parentViewController presentModalViewController:summary animated:YES];
```

When I am trying to do this, I get a warning of:

`warning unable to restore previously selected frame`

and then xcode shows me some assembly language/stack pointing at `uiview(hierarchy)_makesubtreeperformselector` with bad excess crash.

I think the problem is that I am unable to understand the view hierarchy that I have made. What I have got is:

1. There is a viewcontroller, lets say *abc*, which is modally representing a tabbarcontroller named *tabsManager*.
2. tabsManager is managing two viewControllers named as *"int_his"* and *"man_his"*.
3. On a button click in **int_his**, I need to open another tabBarController named *"summaryGraphManager"* modally.

Please can someone tell me how can I correctly present *summaryGraphManager * modally? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
[[self presentingViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

or

[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:login animated:YES];